# VBA use string for range

Tags: vba, excel

I need help for my VBA tool.

In my program I define a string keyword:

```
    Public Sub SetKeyword()

        Call Define_Variables.variables
        Call Database.Allocation

        strKeyword="KINDACC"
```

Now I would like to set the name of the range keyword with my string keyword, so it looks like this:

```
    Public Sub SetKeyword()


        Call Define_Variables.variables
        Call Database.Allocation


        strKeyword="KINDACC"
        rngKeyword= r_KINDACC

     End Sub
```

In my module "Database" I have those r_strKeywords already defined:

```
    Sub Allocation()


    'General accident information
     ...
     Set r_KINDACC = Worksheets("Database").Range("N4:N14")
     End sub
```

So later with my GUI I would like to define a string-keyword and my program automatically defines my range-keyword with my string keyword:

```
     Public Sub SetKeyword()


          Call Define_Variables.variables
          Call Database.Allocation


          strKeyword=blabla
          rngKeyword= r_strKeyword

    End Sub
```

Is that possible?
I hope it's not too confusing

thanks!!

Viktoria

Comment: Would using the [Names Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/names-object-excel) solve your issue?

Comment: The Names collection is the VBA way to access Formulas > Name Manager (or select a Range and give it a name in the box on the left of the Formula Bar) - if you add a name like `ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "KINDACC", Worksheets("Database").Range("N4:N14")` then you can use `ThisWorkbook.Range("KINDACC")` to access the range.

Comment: Ok, the thing is, i have about 300 keywords. So it should automatically set the right range to my rngKeyword.
 
i tried:

        rngKeyword.name="r_" & strKeyword

and it kind of works. But if I change the Keyword it doesn't change my rngKeyword too..

Comment: Once you have set up the Names, you can use `Set rngKeyword = Range(strKeyword)` - this needs calling every time you want to change `rngKeyword`...  OR you just replace all of your `rngKeyword` with `Range(strkeyword)` instead

Comment: Hey Chronocidal, thanks for your help, i tried your first option, which just didn't work, so i replaced everything, and now it works. thanks